# Why are closed questions not automatically unprotected?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, protected-questions

I recently became a pro tem moderator of the Quant Finance SE. I protected a question that eventually was voted to be closed. Even after it was closed, the question was still listed as protected. This seems redundant to me since [protection is to prevent drive-bys](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/). I eventually unprotected the question (and kept it closed) just because **it seems odd to have a question that was protected and closed**.

Is this behaviour intentional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closed questions can be reopened.  Do you want the protection to be removed in the event that a question is reopened?

Comment: Agh. You beat me to it by 20 seconds. ;)